# Pandas group by returns NAN for apply vs transform function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am into couple of situations that I can't explain myself. First thing is about apply vs transform function. So far I understood, apply works on the whole dataframe whereas transform works on each row, hence slower than apply. So here is my dataframe,

```
size    id
40/6    2479
41/7    2479
42/8    2479
43/9    2479
44/10   2479
45/11   2479
46/12   2479
```

Now, when I apply `df.groupby('id')['size'].apply(lambda col: ', '.join(col))` It returns

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
```

But if I transform, `df.groupby('id')['size'].transform(lambda col: ', '.join(col))`, I get

```
0    40/6, 41/7, 42/8, 43/9, 44/10, 45/11, 46/12
1    40/6, 41/7, 42/8, 43/9, 44/10, 45/11, 46/12
2    40/6, 41/7, 42/8, 43/9, 44/10, 45/11, 46/12
3    40/6, 41/7, 42/8, 43/9, 44/10, 45/11, 46/12
4    40/6, 41/7, 42/8, 43/9, 44/10, 45/11, 46/12
5    40/6, 41/7, 42/8, 43/9, 44/10, 45/11, 46/12
6    40/6, 41/7, 42/8, 43/9, 44/10, 45/11, 46/12
```

I want to make it work with apply since I have 3 Million rows and speed is important factor.

**Second issue**

When my size data has empty cells, i.e

```
size    id
        2479
41/7    2479
        2479
43/9    2479
44/10   2479
45/11   2479
46/12   2479
```

using either apply or transform, I get this error, 
`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, float found`
I understand its due to the null value. My question is, how can I overcome this? I need an union of the available values and ignore the null.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for aggregation i.e `df.groupby('id')['size'].agg(lambda col: ', '.join(col))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with `apply`, `lambda` should be omit:

```
df=df.dropna(subset=['size']).groupby('id')['size'].apply(', '.join).reset_index(name='col')
```

Or very similar:

```
df = df['size'].dropna().groupby(df['id']).apply(', '.join).reset_index(name='col')
```

Comment: Amazing @jezrael. Just one more issue. Since it returns 2 items, I can't assign in `df['jointed_size']`. Also What is the best way to learn a lot of csv manipulation with pandas? I will accept your answer.

Comment: Then use `df['jointed_size'] = df['size'].dropna().groupby(df['id']).transform(', '.join)` - get `NaN`s for missing `size` values.